Difficulty Obtaining Bayesfactor in Baysian Correlation in R (correlationBF from BayesFactor)
I am relatively new to Bayesian Analyses and am currently working on computing a Bayesian correlation between two measures of affective polarization (val_pvv and ther_pvv) within my dataset (df_clean). The goal is to quantitatively demonstrate their high degree of similarity.
My approach has been to use the correlationBF function from the BayesFactor package as follows:
cor_pvv_ther_val <- correlationBF(df_clean$val_pvv, df_clean$ther_pvv)

This results in the following warning:
Warning message: In genhypergeo_series_pos(U = c((n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2), L = ((n +  : Series not converged.

Despite this warning, the describe_posterior function provides a summary for the posterior distribution, yet it does not include the Bayes Factor (BF):
describe_posterior(cor_pvv_ther_val)

Summary of Posterior Distribution

Parameter | Median |       95% CI |   pd |          ROPE | % in ROPE | BF |         Prior
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rho       |   0.92 | [0.90, 0.93] | 100% | [-0.05, 0.05] |        0% |    | Beta (3 +- 3)

As can also be seen here:
> extractBF(cor_pvv_ther_val)
          bf error                     time        code
Alt., r=1 NA     0 Wed Apr  3 16:54:41 2024 1f88c5878bf

Given the high median, I suspect the issue with the BF calculation might be related to the extreme correlation value, potentially leading to some issues with the computation of the BF. While the substantial correlation and the low probability of the null model are evident (and the other outputs are quite clear), obtaining the BF would be necessary to be consistent in my analysis reporting. I have the same issue when modifying the rscale argument (e.g., to wide or ultrawide).
I would be very happy about some further information on the warning and about some suggestions on how to solve the issue.
Thank you very much in advance!

Thank you very much for the helpful advice! It makes sense that the numerical precision problem is related to the very large number and I am able to obtain the BF for your example, but I am still unable to obtain a BF when running my code:
cor_pvv_ther_val <- correlationBF(x = df_clean$val_pvv, y = df_clean$ther_pvv, iterations = 999999)

To give a reproducible example, I cannot obtain a Bayes factor in this case either:
correlationBF(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), c(0.7, 2.3, 2.5, 3.8, 5.2, 5.8, 7.5, 8.4, 8.8), iterations = 99999999)

I understand that the Bayes factor does not really provide additional information and may be considered a useless piece of evidence in the described context, but it would be necessary for me to be consistent in the description of my result.

TLDR: I realized the Bayes factor in the OP's example is actually ≈ 0, rather than ≈ ∞. There is no (detectable) evidence to support the hypothesis that the true correlation is 0 given that the observed correlation is 0.99. My first attempt at a solution is in the Calculate BF, take 1 (incorrect) section; my second attempt, hopefully correct, is in the Calculate BF, take 2 section.

In this case the data provides strong evidence against the hypothesis that the correlation coefficient is 0. It seems BayesFactor::correlationBF, which computes the Bayes factor analytically, runs into a numerical precision issue. That's how the hypergeometric function — referred to in the warning about genhypergeo_series_pos — makes an appearance; see Ly et al. (2018) for the mathematical details.
Alternatively, the Bayes factor for a point hypothesis such as $\rho = 0$ can be estimated with the Savage-Dickey density ratio method; with care, this method may work when the analytical calculation fails. First though, it's important to consider that testing the hypothesis that two measures of the same phenomenon are uncorrelated is a more or less needless piece of analysis. If you suspect that one or the other or both measures of affective polarization are not measuring what they claim to measure, hypothesis testing is not an appropriate method to make that argument. The 95% credible interval [0.9, 0.93] eloquently indicates that there is no detectable evidence in favor of the hypothesis that the correlation is 0.
Nevertheless, let's proceed with Bayes factor calculation. The Savage-Dickey density ratio is the ratio of the posterior density to the prior density at the null hypothesis $\rho = 0$; see this answer by @mef for a derivation. If the ratio is > 1, the mass of the posterior distribution has shifted closer to $\rho = 0$ compared to the mass of the prior. In other words, the evidence in favor of the null hypothesis has increased after seeing the data. We can estimate the densities at the point $\rho = 0$ by drawing a sample from the prior and a sample from the posterior. I'll use 50,000 draws as Bayes factors can be unstable esp. in complex statistical models (Schad et al., 2023).
library("bayestestR")
library("BayesFactor")
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
y <- c(0.7, 2.3, 2.5, 3.8, 5.2, 5.8, 7.5, 8.4, 8.8)

cor(x, y)
#> [1] 0.9933628

rscale <- 1 / 3
N <- 50000

# Draw from the posterior instead of calculating the Bayes factor.
draws <- correlationBF(x, y, posterior = TRUE, iterations = N)
posterior <- as.numeric(draws[, "rho"])

# Draw from the prior as well. `correlationBF()` actually returns
# a sample from the posterior only but according to the documentation,
# it puts a shifted, scaled beta(1 / rscale, 1 / rscale) prior on rho.
# The draws are in the [0,1] range, so I transform them to the [-1,1] range.
prior <- 2 * rbeta(N, 1 / rscale, 1 / rscale) - 1

Calculate BF, take 1 (incorrect)
Now we have the ingredients to calculate the Savage-Dickey density density ratio for $\rho = 0$: samples from the prior and the posterior. Let's do the calculation with bayestestR::bf_pointnull.
# Compute the Bayes factor in terms of the Savage-Dickey density ratio.
bf_pointnull(posterior, prior, null = 0)
#> Bayes Factor (Savage-Dickey density ratio)
#> 
#> BF      
#> --------
#> 3.08e+43

Unfortunately, this BF estimate is incorrect: the data provides no support for $\rho = 0$, rather than effectively infinite support. As always, it helps to make a plot. Here are histograms of the prior and the posterior draws side by side. Given the data $x$ and $y$, the evidence for a strong positive correlation is such that we get no value < 0.8 in 50,000 draws from the posterior $\rho | x,y$.

From the histograms, we conclude that the posterior density is ≈ 0 at $\rho = 0$ while the prior density is positive. So the Savage-Dickey ratio (and thus the Bayes factor in favor of $\rho = 0$) is also ≈ 0.
Calculate BF, take 2
The issue with the calculation is in the very last step: bf_pointnull() uses logspline::oldlogspline and, I suspect, the spline approximation fails at $\rho = 0$ because the entire posterior sample falls in the interval [0.85, 1.0] far away from 0.
I experimented with methods to estimate the density ratio $f(\rho | x,y) / f(\rho)$ directly. (That is, estimate the density ratio itself rather than estimate the prior and posterior density separately and then take their ratio. The {densratio} package came in handy.
library("densratio")

# I experimented with the sigma and lambda parameters a bit
# to choose (what seem to be) reasonable values for this situation.
posterior_to_prior <- densratio(posterior, prior, sigma = 0.01, lambda = 0.001)
#> ################## Start RuLSIF ##################
#> Optimizing kernel weights...
#> End.
#> ################## Finished RuLSIF ###############
posterior_to_prior$compute_density_ratio(0)
#> [1] 0

This method has its own numerical accuracy issues, mostly for large values of $\rho > 0.9$.
In the end, the problem is not so much with the computation but with the hypothesis. In fact, I interpret the computational challenges as a hint not to calculate the Bayes factor in the first place. The samples from the prior and the posterior already tell me that the Savage-Dickey ratio is numerically about 0.

Lessons learned:

Reconsider the impulse to test hypotheses known to be false.
We need many more posterior draws to estimate a Bayes factor than to estimate a posterior probability or a credible interval.
Even with a large sample, the density estimation required for the Savage-Dickey density ratio method can fail dramatically.

References:

Ly, A., Marsman, M., and Wagenmakers, E.-J. (2018) Analytic posteriors for Pearson's correlation coefficient. Statistica Neerlandica, 72: 4–13. doi: 10.1111/stan.12111. 
Schad, D. J., Nicenboim, B., Bürkner, P.-C., Betancourt, M., & Vasishth, S. (2023). Workflow techniques for the robust use of bayes factors. Psychological Methods, 28(6), 1404–1426. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000472 


Thank you very much for this first reply. I still have some problems with the calculation of the Bayesfactor and will give some more explanation in a reply, due to the word count/format of this comment section.

Hello. I saw the example you've provided. (Please note that you should edit your question instead.) So what (I think) is happening here is that the BF is close to infinity and there are limits to the very big or very small number can be calculated and represented as double-precision floating-point number. I'll again suggest that there is no value added in a formal test whether population correlation coefficient is 0 when the observed rho is 0.99.

That was super helpful! Thank you very much!

@JKas I hope you haven't submitted your results. I discovered I've messed up the calculation (more computational issues), and the Bayes factor is actually 0, not infinity. Sorry about the mis-direction! I thought the BF is the evidence in favor of the alternative (and then BF = infinity in favor of the alternative means BF = 0 in favor of the null). I also wrote up how to calculate the Bayes factor with {brms} (awesome R package for fitting Bayesian models). {brms} also reports BF = 0, so hopefully that settles it.

In R, an alternative way to estimate the Bayes factor for the correlation coefficient is to use {brms}. In the situation faced by the OP (the true correlation is very far from the point of interest), the computation with {brms} is more robust than with {BayesFactor}. {brms} uses the Savage-Dickey density ratio method to test two-sided (point) hypotheses; see (Wagenmakers et al, 2010) and the other answer for details.
Let's start with how {BayesFactor} formalizes the computation of a Bayes factor for the correlation $\rho$. The documentation explains:

The Bayes factor tests the null hypothesis that the true linear correlation ρ between two samples (x and y) of size n from normal populations is equal to 0. (...) Noninformative priors are assumed for the population means and variances of the two population; a shifted, scaled beta(1/rscale,1/rscale) prior distribution is assumed for ρ.

We'll use the same formulation, with different priors.
So let's assume the paired observations $(X_i, Y_i)$ come from a bivariate normal distribution with means $\mu_x,\mu_y$, standard deviations $\sigma_x,\sigma_y$ and correlation $\rho$. And let's put weakly informative priors on the means and the standard deviations and a LKJ prior on the correlation matrix, ie. the 2×2 matrix with 1s on the diagonal and $\rho$ off the diagonal. The LKJ prior is recommended by the Stan team ({brms} uses Stan to do Bayesian inference); see their Prior Choice Recommendations.
The estimation proceeds in two steps: (a) MCMC sampling with brms::brm to fit the bivariate normal model, and (b) hypothesis testing with brms::hypothesis to compute an evidence ratio (ie. Bayes factor in the case of a point hypothesis such as $\rho = 0$).
library("brms")

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
y <- c(0.7, 2.3, 2.5, 3.8, 5.2, 5.8, 7.5, 8.4, 8.8)

# Specify a multivariate model for two responses, x and y.
# The variables are correlated as rescor is set to TRUE.
model <- mvbf(
  x ~ 1,
  y ~ 1,
  rescor = TRUE
)

# Specify the priors.
priors <- c(
  # Normal prior on the population means, centered at the observed means
  prior(normal(5, 10), class = Intercept, resp = x),
  prior(normal(5, 10), class = Intercept, resp = y),
  # Student-t prior on the standard deviations
  prior(student_t(3, 0, 2.5), class = sigma, resp = x),
  prior(student_t(3, 0, 2.5), class = sigma, resp = y),
  # LKJ prior on the correlation.
  prior(lkj(1), class = rescor)
)

# Fit the bivariate normal model.
fit <- brm(
  model,
  prior = priors,
  data = data.frame(x, y),
  sample_prior = "yes",
  warmup = 1000,
  iter = 11000
)

# Test the point hypothesis that the correlation between x and y,
# called rescor__x__y internally by {brms} is equal to 0.
hyp <- hypothesis(fit, "rescor__x__y = 0", class = "")
hyp
#>         Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob
#> (rescor__x__y) = 0     0.98      0.03     0.92        1          0         0
#> ---
#> 'CI': 90%-CI for one-sided and 95%-CI for two-sided hypotheses.
#> Posterior probabilities of point hypotheses assume equal prior probabilities.

The Bayes factor is given by the evidence ratio, Evid.ratio, in the table above. The BF is estimated to be 0: the data provides evidence that x and y are strongly correlated and no support for the point hypothesis $\rho = 0$.
It's straightforward and also quite informative to superimpose the two densities — prior and posterior — in the same plot. Compared to the side-by-side histograms from the other answer, we get more resolution with the overlaid densities but the message is the same: while the prior puts non-negligible mass on/near $\rho = 0$, the posterior doesn't. So the Savage-Dickey density ratio, ie. the Bayes factor, is approximately 0.
plot(hyp)


Reference:
Wagenmakers EJ, Lodewyckx T, Kuriyal H, Grasman R. Bayesian hypothesis testing for psychologists: a tutorial on the Savage-Dickey method. Cognitive Psychology. 2010 May;60(3):158-189. DOI: 10.1016/j.cogpsych.2009.12.001. PMID: 20064637.
